# Formatting feedback for First Answers review queue

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, first-answers

During reviews in First Answers queue, there are a lot of answers without code blocks, syntax highlighting, formatting, or linebreaks. It would be nice to have a Share Feedback action that suggests to use formatting (for now, we must share feedback as ourselves to do that).

I suggest the following feedback:

> **Answer needs formatting**
> Your answer could be improved with additional formatting. Please *[edit]* to add further markdown, such as code blocks or linebreaks, so that others can easily read your answer. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: I suggest making "help center" a link to [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: I suggest the following feedback: downvote.

Comment: @TGrif The downvote doesn't say why. Maybe the person just don't know how to format code, that's why the link to "How to format post with markdown" is more usefull than just downvote

Comment: [There **is** an option you can choose for answers which just need formatting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RYgHa.png)

Comment: @VLAZ With less than 2k rep, it's limited and sometimes we can't do it

Comment: @Elikill58 I don't think that means that there should be a comment posted that says "do it yourself". Yes, the edit queue being full is a problem but I don't think all other queues should be designed around that.

Comment: A similar question was raised recently. Sadly, it is now deleted, but for 10k+: [Missing action "Recommend Edit" in Late Answers Review Queue?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/416031/6045800)

Comment: @Tomerikoo your question is for another queue

Comment: I'm aware. The core is the same: why post feedback for editing if you can just suggest an edit? If the answer is not clear and you're not sure how to edit, put the feedback for unclear answer. No reason for a new message...

Comment: The goal of feedbacks is "feedbacks": this is First Answers queue, and the goal is to help and teach new users how to write good messages by themselves in the future, not doing it for them.

Answer (score -1):

### Lead by example!

If you can improve the formatting of the post, then you should do so by editing it.

### Be the change you want to see.

Take the action you think needs to be taken in order to make the site better. This is the whole point of reviewing. When you see something that you have the power to fix, don't leave a useless comment. That doesn't help anyone. Don't try to make it someone else's problem. If the author knew how to format it better, they would have done so. However, they can surely learn how to improve their formatting in future posts by following the good example that you set for them on this one.

Also, more practically, many first-time posters never bother to return, so these comments just sit around uselessly forever, while the poorly-formatted post sits there untouched, stinking up the place…until someone finally takes the time to submit an edit that fixes it. Please be a part of the solution, not a part of the <strike>precipitate</strike> problem.

### Therefore, we should not implement this feature.

No one should leave "feedback" like this. In fact, all or nearly all of the canned "feedback" options are just useless noise that is not helping anyone. It serves little purpose but to clutter up the site. Either fix the post by editing it, flag it to bring it to a moderator's attention if it needs to be deleted, or indicate your feelings about its quality/usefulness with a downvote. Comments should be reserved for when you have something *unique and substantive* to say about how the post could be improved, like "This code will work, but you should prefer to use the Streams API when targeting Java 8 or later." Or in cases where you *cannot* fix the problem yourself, like when the author has forgotten key information.

Comment: Totally disagree. **Edit queue is often full**, moreover if we tell the user how to use the formatting he/she will learn something and the next time will be able to write a better answer.